# discordjs my bot runs correctly when running locally but not with heroku

Tags: discord.js

so if someone tries to run a command in a certain channel, my bot will (or should) delete the command and tell the user not to run commands in that channel, here's my code for that:

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.channel.type === 'dm' || msg.author.id === bot.user.id || msg.author.id === '706663416697192489'){
    return;
    }
    else if(msg.content.startsWith("!") && msg.channel.id === '706662574606778490'){
    msg.delete()
    msg.reply('you can\'t send commands in this channel! Send commands in the <#707068673399193670> channel.').then(function(msg){
    msg.delete({timeout: 2000})
    })
    }
});
```

this code works perfectly fine when i run my bot locally with ctrl+c "node .", but normally i run my bot with heroku so its running full time. the problem is when i run this code with heroku, the reply message doesn't get deleted. this isn't too good as if someone tries to run a command in my announcements channel, the command will be deleted but the bot's reply message wont be and everyone can see "you can\'t send commands in this channel! Send commands in the <#707068673399193670> channel." in announcements. all my other code works perfectly fine with heroku, except this. i feel this might be an issue on heroku's part but any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not heroku's fault, you had duplicate variable names

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type === 'dm' || msg.author.id === bot.user.id || msg.author.id === '706663416697192489') return;
    if (msg.content.startsWith("!") && msg.channel.id === '706662574606778490') {
        msg.delete();
        msg.reply('you can\'t send commands in this channel! Send commands in the <#707068673399193670> channel.')
            .then(reply => reply.delete({ timeout: 2000 }));
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem, I've seen a few posts where you admit an answer, but you don't accept it. You're new here so it's fine, but you should start accepting them, so if people in the future stumble upon it, they can instantly find it or so they don't think it's still an issue and try to give another solution.

Comment: how would I admit an answer